# "That of being"

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> He then spends the rest of his life trying to expiate his dual sin:
>   ***That of being*** furious at his mother for not satisfying him; ***that of being*** such a greedy child who really deserves nothing better. ([Source](https://www.positivedisintegration.com/Garber1976.pdf))

What does "that of being" mean?

I suppose it is used to avoid writing "dual sin" again and again. But I don't understand the construction of "that of being"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your source uses the expression "dual sin", it means that the sin has a "dual" nature, in other words the sin is composed of two parts. The section of the sentence following the colon identifies (in turn) each part of the sin.

It could have been written this way:

> "... dual sin: The sin of being furious at his mother for not
>   satisfying him; and the sin of being such a greedy child who really
>   deserves nothing better."

Where "of" is the preposition used in English to identify a particular sin. (e.g. "the sin **of** pride", "the sin **of** gluttony", ...)

But, as you speculate, the author probably felt that writing the word "sin" three times in one sentence was just a little too annoying to the reader. So he replaced the second two "**the sin**"s with the pronoun **that**.

Comment: Thank you. I was going to ask why "of" was used but you have already covered that part. :)

Comment: Can "this" be used instead "of "that" to indicate the sin?

Comment: Do you mean to replace both "**that**"s directly with "this", and no other changes to the sentence? If you mean: "... dual sin: **This** of being furious at his mother for not satisfying him; **this** of being such a greedy child ..." then, no. The sentence doesn't work with "**this**". I *think* it is because even though "this" can be a demonstrative pronoun (substituting for a noun), when you say "this", you mean a subject (conceptually) *close* to you, so it should be obvious what "**this**" refers to. Further qualification ("...of being furious", etc.), isn't appropriate with "this".